# A sentence in Folland's Introduction to Partial Differential Equations

Tags: general-topology, partial-differential-equations

This is a sentence in Folland's **Introduction to Partial Differential Equations----chapter 3**:

> In this chapter $\Omega$ will be a fixed bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $C^2$ boundary $S$, and we set $\Omega'=\mathbb{R}^n-\overline{\Omega}$. $\Omega$ and $\Omega'$ will both be allowed to be disconnected; however, since $S$ is differentiable there can only be finitely many components.

I want to know how to prove it? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What is a $C^2$ boundary? How can a boundary (which is a *set*) be differentiable?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I guess it means that it is a $C^2$ submanifold of $\mathbb R^n$, or that it is locally written as a graph of a $C^2$ function.

Comment: @ArcticChar then boundedness is essential as otherwise we could have a disjoint union of circle areas. Boundedness would force an accumulation point, where things would be non-differentiable.